# using List for first names

Tags: c#

I am getting errors on my first names and other areas and I don't know if it is a basic logic error or my concept. In my PromptName() it seems to be not returing anything along with my Display(index, searchedName);

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Seven
{
class Seven
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // IMPORTANT CODE REQUIREMENT: In the following list              declaration, 
        //  the order of the items in firstNames 
        //  cannot be "manually" changed.
        // ------------------------------------------------
        List<string> firstNames = { "Johnny", "Alice", "Cory",
                            "Steve", "Dennis" };
        // ------------------------------------------------

        int index;
        string searchedName = PromptName();
        while (searchedName.Equals("end"))
        {
            index = firstNames.BinarySearch(serchedName);
            Display(index, searchedName);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    private void Display(int index, string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes, {0} is in our course.", searchedName);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No, {0} is not in our course.", name);
        }
        Console.Write("");
    }

    private string PromptName()
    {
        Console.Write("To terminate the program, enter 'end' for the student name.");
        Console.Write("Enter the first name of the student to be searched in our course: ");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, where *specifically* does it fail?  (Hint: `while (searchedName.Equals("end"))` doesn't seem to make much sense.  For one thing, you'd want to perform the logic when the input *doesn't* equal `"end"`.  Additionally, why is that a loop at all?  I think you're looking for an `if` statement there.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` loop does not execute unless PromptName() *does* return "end".

Change

```
while (searchedName.Equals("end"))
```

to

```
while (!searchedName.Equals("end"))
```

You have an additional problem that you do not prompt for a new name again. Do that at the end of your while loop, right after your call to Display().

This is the type of problem that is easily resolved with a debugger. If you have not yet learned how to use one in your environment, I would suggest prioritizing it. The time you invest in learning to debug will quickly pay for itself.

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that your list is not declared properly. It should be

```
List<string> firstNames = new List<string>() { "Johnny", "Alice", "Cory",
                        "Steve", "Dennis" };
```

Comment: It would be nice to know how to use everything visual logic has to offer but my teachers don't care about teaching us how to step through a program..I always have problems with visual studio 2015 for example when I try to run a new program it'll run the old program even when it is closed.

Comment: For this small program, you could just keep pressing F11 in Visual Studio to follow every single step in the program, and mouse over variables to see what values they have. Visual Studio only runs the old version if there were errors compiling your code, but it prompts you first. The prompt tells you that there were errors and asks if you want to run the old version instead (which you should always say no to, and instead fix the compile errors).

Comment: List<string> firstNames = { "Johnny", "Alice", "Cory",
                                "Steve", "Dennis" };
           
            int index;
            string searchedName = PromptName();
            while (!searchedName.Equals("end"))
            {
                index = firstNames.BinarySearch(serchedName);
                Display(index, searchedName);
                PromptName();
            }
            
            Console.Read();
        }

Comment: I still get the same errors all my names are underlined red

Comment: I still have errors right before my while loop  string searchedName = PromptName(); and within my while loop the Display(Index, searchedName);

Answer (score 0):

You may already know this, but on line 25 there is a typo:

Line 25: index = firstNames.BinarySearch(serchedName);

serchedName should be searchedName